# Excel - counting names in an column that have non blank columns adjacent to them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count the number of names in Column A that do not have blank cells adjacent to them in Column B .. I've tried several combinations of countif, countifs, counta .. and all i can get it to do is add the results together.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be something like the following, using wildcards:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*",B:B,"*")
```

Comment: YEP! ... i used '=COUNTIFS($C$48:$C$62,R48,$G$48:$G$62,"<>")' and it worked perfectly.. thanks!